# Is multiple regression the best approach for optimization?

Tags: optimization, linear-regression, data-science

I am being asked to take a look at a scenario where a company has many projects that they wish to complete, but with any company budget comes into play. There is a Y value of a predefined score, with multiple X inputs. There are also 3 main constraints of Capital Costs, Expense Cost and Time for Completion in Months.

The ask is could an algorithmic approach be used to optimize which projects should be done for the year given the 3 constraints. The approach also should give different results if the constraint values change. The suggested method is multiple regression. Though I have looked into different approaches in detail. I would like to ask the wider community, if anyone has dealt with a similar problem, and what approaches have you used.

Comment: I think what you are talking about is related to the `capital budgeting problem`. This is not solved by regression, but rather by optimization methods.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I had took the optimization approach, but algorithms such as genetic or particle swarm are process optimizing with iterative tests. I do 100% agree, I do think regression will not solve this, and only that it was given to me as a directive, it would not have been on the radar.

Comment: The models I worked on used LP and MIP (linear and mixed integer programming). There was no good reason to use heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt thing we should understood, a conclution of something is not base on one argument.

this is from communication theory, that every human make a frame of knowledge (understanding conclution), where the frame construct from many piece of knowledge / information).

the concequence is we cannot use single linear regression in math to create  a ML / DL system.

at least we should use two different variabel to make a sub conclution. if we push to use single variable with use linear regression (`y=mx+c`). it's similar to push computer predict something with low accuration. what ever optimization method that you pick...it's still low accuracy..., why...because linear regresion if you use in real life, it similar with predict 'habbit' base on data, not calculating the real condition.

that's means...., we should use multiple linear regression (`y=m1x1+m2x2+ ... + c`) to calculate anything in order to make computer understood / have conclution / create model of regression. but, not so simple like it. because of computer try to make a conclution from data that have multiple character / varians ... you must classified the data and the conclution.

for an example, try to make computer understood phitagoras.
we know that phitagoras formula is `c=((a^2)+(b^2))^(1/2)`, and we want our computer can make prediction the phitagoras side (`c`) from two input values (`a` and `b`). so to do that, we should make a model or a mutiple linear regresion formula of phitagoras. 
step 1 of course we should make a multi character data of phitagoras.

this is an example

```
a         b            c
3         4            5
8         6            10
3         14           etc..., try put 10 until 20 data
```

try to make a conclution of regression formula with multiple regression to predic the c base on a and b values.

you will found that some data have high accuration (higher than 98%) for some value and some value is not to accurate (under 90%). example a=3 and b=14 or b=15, will give low accuration result (under 90%).

so you must make and optimization....but how to do it...

I know many method to optimize, but i found in manual way, if I exclude the data that giving low accuracy result and put them in different group then, recalculate again to the data group that excluded, i will get more significant result. do again...until you reach the accuracy target that you want.

each group data, that have a new regression, is a new class.

means i will have several multiple regression base on data that i input (the regression come from each group of data / class) and the accuracy is really high, 99% - 99.99%.

and with the several class, the regresion have a fuction as a 'label' of the class, this is what happens in the backgroud of the automation computation. but with many module, the user of the module, feel put 'string' object as label, but the truth is, the string object binding to a regresion that constructed as label.

with some conditional parameter you can get the good ML with minimum number of data train.

try it on excel / libreoffice before step more further...

try to follow the tutorial from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-k84cCves8)

and implement it in simple data that easy to construct in excel, like pythagoras.

so the answer is yes...the multiple regression is the best approach for optimization.